# Play Framework 2.0 Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

Having a very basic issue with running tests in a Java Play 2.0 app. It won't pick up my tests.

I've tried to put a `test` folder in the root of the project and use Junit as the docs seem to suggest. This results in:

```
$ play test
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/.../play20TestTest/project
[info] Set current project to play20TestTest (in build     file:/Users/.../testapps/play20TestTest/)
[info] No tests to run for test:test
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed May 22, 2012 11:16:52 AM
```

I've also tried putting `test` under app. This at least picks up my code, but the test packages aren't available on my classpath so I assume it's incorrect.

I made a simple example and copied SimpleTest from the docs exactly: https://github.com/jsimone/Play2UnitTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed your test in `test/test/SimpleTest.java`, move it to `test/SimpleTest.java` and it will work with `play test` command.

Comment: Ahh... I see now. That still fails for me unless I run `play clean` in between. That's what I must have been missing when I was messing with this. Thanks!

Comment: So then is the SimpleTest in the docs is actually incorrect since it has `package test`?